# Set selected item in a databound list box

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a wpf listbox that is bound to a datatable. At some times, I want to programmaticly change the selection of the listbox. I know the text of the item I want to select. But it doesn't work to set the listbox1.SelectedItem to the text I want because the type of the SelectedItem is System.Data.DataRowView.

If I have the text I want to select and the DataRow that I want to select, what is the easiest way select the associated row in the list box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search through your `DataSet` and find the appropriate `DataRow`. Then set `SelectedItem` to that `DataRow`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the text, then it would be:

```
ListBox1.SelectedValue = ListBox1.Items.FindByText("Two").Value;
```

You can also use the SelectedIndex property to set the selected value by 0-based index.

Comment: listBox1.Items doesn't have a FindByText method.

Answer (score 0):

The ListBox control (both in Forms and WebControls) has a SelectedValue property that:

> "Gets the value of the selected item in the list control, or selects the item in the list control that contains the specified value."

You could use this to select the item based on it's value, typically a unique key.

More info from MSDN:

[System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx)

[System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx)

Comment: I didn't say it in the question, but the question was tagged wpf.